# Extract data from different formatted data dumps

Tags: php, oop

For my current project I have to parse data "dumps" (EEPROM HEX dumps from a microcontroller) (coming from a file or a SQL database) that have a different format depending on the version of the software in the controller. (The software version is also in the dump.)

Extracting the version works and I have a somewhat working version that works for 1 specific version (but I find the current version quite messy). Since there is some overlap the between the different versions.

The output of the code is a JSON array that is fed to angular that formats the data into a table so a user can start playing with the data. (the JSON is generated with `json_encode`, works great)

What I'm looking for is a nice (oop, if possible) solution what can extract the data from the different file versions without a lot of code copy-paste. The only solution I can think of right now would be class for the 1st version, and than do a copy-paste (and a little edit) to a new class the 2nd version (and so on).

A generic answer on how to do this is fine for me, however I'm trying to do this in PHP.

Comment: `do a copy-paste (and a little edit) to a new class` Perhaps it's time to start learning about inheritance in OOP

Comment: @MarkBaker That's why I'm asking. I know about inheritance but I have no clue on how to implement this correctly. I could make a _huge_ parent class but I have the feeling that that would result in even more code spaghetti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by making a base class and a child class for the first version (the following code may not have perfect syntax):

```
class DataDump {
     // some kind of storage
     protected $contents;    

}

class FirstVersion extends DataDump {

}
```

Then as you are building the `FirstVersion` class, try to pay close attention to what you think might be common in all the versions and move that code down to the DataDump parent class.

```
class DataDump {

     // some kind of storage
     protected $contents;  

     public loadFile($filename) {
          ....code....
          $this->contents = ...
     }

     public processHeader() {

     }
}

class FirstVersion extends DataDump {
     public loadFirstFile {

        $this->loadFile(...);

        $this->processHeader();

        ...some code specific to this version...

     }
}
```

Then you can slowly build the parent class with the things that are common, and there is almost always parts of the code that are common (even if in small segments).  As you build other child classes, you may find other logic that can be shared, so push it down to the parent, or perhaps there is a base method that some of the child classes override and others can just use the base method.

Sometimes, when you have a big mess to deal with, it is hard to see all the shared code upfront and how to best organize it in a sane way, and this process helps tremendously when you are stuck.  Just start writing and you will begin to see the patterns among all the versions, even if just helper methods.